# Recreating XML but passing variable into the data

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to Create an XML with the below format but keep having issues. I am new to both c# and XML and hit a brick wall on this one. The reference XML i have is this

```
<workspace name="Remote Apps" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ts/2008/09/tswcx" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <defaultFeed url="CHANGEME" />
</workspace>
```

I need to be able to recreate this file with the adjustment of the url Value. I have tried loading this XML on its own and the alter the value and also tried to recreate from scratch. Both i have hit a blank wall.

Last attempt to do this was

```cs
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("cloud.xml");
            var element = doc.Elements("defaultFeed")
                 .Single(x => x.Attribute("url").Value == "ChangeMe");

            element.SetAttributeValue("url", fullurl);

            doc.Save(CloudFileLocation);
```

If someone would be kind enough to help me out with this either writing from scratch or altering the code from a local file i would appreciate it. (Create from scratch would be preferred)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three probems with your code:

1. `doc.Elements("defaultFeed")` searches for an element named defaultFeed as child of the document. Your element is however a child of the root node `workspace`.

Solution: change to

```
doc.Root.Elements("defaultFeed")
```

2. This attribute `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ts/2008/09/tswcx"` says that all elements where the namespace is not explicitely specified, are in the namespace `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ts/2008/09/tswcx`. `Elements("defaultFeed")` however searches for elements without any namespace.

Solution: change to

```
XNamespace tswcx = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ts/2008/09/tswcx";
doc.Root.Elements(tswcx + "defaultFeed")
```

3. The third one is a simple typo: You should compare to "CHANGEME", not to "ChangeMe"

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me! i think the issue i was having was not mentioning the namespace. i adjusted to this https://pastebin.com/wZPaynYw

Comment: So your issue is solved then? You might consider accepting the answer.